# How change zip archive download folder for embedpostgresql?

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, embedpostgresql

[Here](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded) is embedpostgresql library for starting a postgres process via java. The [instruction](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded#how-to-use-avoid-archive-extraction-on-every-run) about reusing already extracted postgres from zip archive. But how to change archive directory? By default they store maven to `%USER_HOME\.embedpostgresql%` I want to change it to maven repository but what is needed to invoke to set such property?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the **artifactStorePath()** method from *DownloadConfigBuilder* class:

```
final FixedPath cachedDir = new FixedPath("/tmp/cacheddir");
final FixedPath artifactStoreDir = new FixedPath("/tmp/artstoredir");
 IRuntimeConfig runtimeConfig = new RuntimeConfigBuilder().defaults(cmd)
 .artifactStore(new CachedArtifactStoreBuilder()
         .defaults(cmd)
         .tempDir(cachedDir)
         .download(new DownloadConfigBuilder()
                 .defaultsForCommand(cmd)
                 .artifactStorePath(artifactStoreDir)
                 .packageResolver(new PackagePaths(cmd, cachedDir))
                 .build()))
 .build();

//starting Postgres
 final PostgresStarter<PostgresExecutable, PostgresProcess> runtime =
 PostgresStarter.getInstance(runtimeConfig);
```

I cloned the [git repository](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded), did a 'grep -R embedpostgresql *' and found the first hint in ru.yandex.qatools.embed.postgresql.config.DownloadConfigBuilder class. Then I tested by myself and it works!